# Why is $(\forall x \in \mathbb{Z})(\exists y \in \mathbb{Z}) (2x + y = 3 \to x + 2y = 3)$ true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

> Is the statement true or false? $$(\forall x \in \mathbb{Z})(\exists y \in \mathbb{Z}) (2x + y = 3 \to x + 2y = 3)$$ The answer is that the entire statement is true, but I do not see why.

The first part of the equation $2x + y = 3$ would be true since for every $x$ there is at least one that satisfies the equation. The right is false, since there for every $x$ there is not at least one $y$ that satisfies the equation. But this would make the conditional statement false since the left is true and the right is false?

Comment: Hint: what if $2x+y=3$ is false

Comment: Let $y = -2x$, how would you evaluate the truth of the statement then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No matter which $x$ you come with, I can choose an $y$ that makes both sides of the $\to$ *false*, and therefore makes the entire $\to$ *true*.

The meaning of formulas of the form $\exists x(\cdots \to \cdots)$ is not very intuitive; the $\to$ connective is really designed to live under a $\forall$ instead. In my experience, the best one can do for getting an intuitive handle on the is to expand it using $p\to q \equiv \neg p \lor q$. Then you get
$$(\forall x \in \mathbb{Z})(\exists y \in \mathbb{Z}) (2x + y \neq 3 \lor x + 2y = 3)$$
and it should be easiler to convince yourself that there is always an $y$ that makes $2x+y\neq 3$ hold ...

Comment: The question reads like the poster is mentally separating the quantifiers over the implication, like $(\forall x \exists y .2x+y = 3) \to (\forall x \exists y .x + 2y=3)$.

Comment: @DanielV: Hmm, yes. If you can come up with an explanation that addresses _that_ particular misreading, by all means post it as an alternative answer.

Comment: Okay I see now, that's a better way of looking at it. I see the mistake I was making before, thank you.

Comment: @DanielV That was the mistake I was making, good catch

Comment: @boobzRkewl33: Neither the universal nor existential quantifier distributes over $\to$.

Comment: @DanielV Since you can distribute the universal quantifier but not the existential would this be valid? $\exists y(\forall x 2x+y = 3 \to \forall x  x + 2y=3)$

Comment: @Henning Makholm Neither?

Comment: @boobzRkewl33: Neither. $\forall x(x=1 \to x=2)$ is false (it fails when $x$ is $1$), but $(\forall x.x=1)\to(\forall x.x=2)$ is true (because both sides are false). And in any case, $\forall$ and $\exists$ do not _commute_ either, so you can't move the $\forall x$ inside the $\exists y$ in the first place.

Comment: @boobzRkewl33 Afraid that doesn't work either.  $y$ is a function of $x$.  So if Alice says "this is true" bob says "ok then what is the $y$" then alice is allowed to respond with a $y$ which depends on $x$, like $y=-2x$

Comment: @Henning Makholm Ah, thanks. I was confusing that with the distribution of the universal and existential over conjunctions. Okay so they can't commute, I was wondering earlier if that was even a valid operation.

Answer (score 0):

$A\to B$ is equivalent to $((\neg A)\lor B).$ So if $A$ is false then $A\to B$ is true. So $(\neg A) \implies (\;(\neg A)\land((\neg A)\lor B)\;)\implies (A\to B).$

So if $A$ is $2x+y=3,$  and $B$ is anything, then $\forall x\in \Bbb Z\;\exists y\in \Bbb Z\;(A\to B)$ is true if $\forall x\in \Bbb Z\;\exists y\in \Bbb Z\;(\neg A)$ is true.

In detail $$\forall x\in \Bbb Z\; \exists y\in \Bbb Z\;(y\ne 3-2x)\implies$$ $$\implies \forall x\;\exists y\in \Bbb Z\;(\neg A)\implies$$ $$\implies \forall x\in \Bbb Z\;\exists y\in \Bbb Z\;(\neg  A\land (A\to B))\implies$$ $$\implies \forall x\in \Bbb Z\;\exists Y\in \Bbb Z\;(A\to B).$$